# Node disappears after restart server. Neo4j 3.0 Cypher 3

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to add a node to my base, but every time I restart the server, the node disappears along with their relationships.

I started my base by importing a CSV using the ./neo4j-import script in the bin folder. The node in question is a node that connects to all subgraphs of my base (like a root node), turning the base into a connected graph.

I already added through the shell (./neo4j-shell) through the web application and using python (using `from neo4j.v1 driver import GraphDatabase`), in all cases when I restart the server, the node disappears.

The command I am using in all approaches is this:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ create(r:PDB{name: 'root', resolution: 'less than 2.0', method: 'x-ray diffraction'}); 

neo4j-sh (?)$ match(r:PDB{name:'root'}) match(p:PDB_FILE) merge(r)-[:HAS_PDB]->(p);
```

In the latest attempt used differently (using `commit`):

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ begin 

neo4j-sh (?)$ create(r:PDB{name: 'root', resolution: 'less than 2.0', method: 'x-ray diffraction'}); 

neo4j-sh (?)$ match(r:PDB{name:'root'}) match(p:PDB_FILE) merge(r)-[:HAS_PDB]->(p);

neo4j-sh (?)$ commit
```

But without success.

I'm using version 3.0. * of Neo4j, Cypher 3.0, Ubuntu 4.14 server.

Comment: Can you share more details about your import? And config of your server. And how you run neo4j-shell

Comment: Well, I following  the official documentation to import a csv file available [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#import-tool). Everything went well, without errors.
  My configuration files are available [here](http://notepad.cc/jrenato-neo4jconfig).
  And I'm running neo4j-shell from the folder `~/neo4j-community-3.0.3/bin/`, but I also tried create the node from python code and from neo4j web application, and always when I restart the server, the node disappears. That didn't happen with relationships between nodes that were added during the import action.

Comment: The second links is broken and I can't edit. So [here](https://anotepad.com/notes/7i32en) is the new (My configuration files).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea on why this is happening to you, but what I would definitely try is using the super batch importer for huge datasets: `neo4j-import`. There is some instruction on how to use the tool [in neo4j documentation](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_super_fast_batch_importer_for_huge_datasets).

To use the tool you have to put your data in special formats, individual csv files each corresponding to a type of node or a type of edge in your dataset. It is well explained in the given link, and, even though it does not explain *why* this is happening to you, it is surely worth a try.

Another things that you could try are:

- to install *neo4j* in another machine. Maybe there is some weird problem with your installation/your system;
- try another version of neo4j. I'm not totally aware, but I imagine the latter 2.X.X versions should be more stable than the newer ones, as *Neo4j v3* has been release recently. It is easy to install any version using [this debian repositories](http://debian.neo4j.org/) (via apt-get in Ubuntu).